# Nevron DockPanel - resize grip handles

Tags: docking, dockpanel, nevron

Nevron's dock panel grip handles are only a few pixels wide when used on a 4k monitor. This makes resizing a panel tedious to get the mouse exactly over the panel border so the grip handles show. Is there a setting to increase the grip handle size?

Writing my own code in the MouseMove event won't fire due to other controls in the dock panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NDockManager object has a property called SplitterStyle. You can set the size of the splitter style to some int value which will increase the width of the splitter to the desired size:

m_DockManager.SplitterStyle.Size = mySplitterWidth;